# PHP Find an Array inside a multi-dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I want to find an array inside a multi dimensional array using PHP.

For example:

```
$arr = array(

    '1253' => array('0' => 'av/data'),
    '1254' => array('1' => 'celling', '2' => 'electrical'),
    '1255' => array('1' => 'celling', '2' => 'electrical'),
);
```

Want to search for

```
array('1' => 'celling', '2' => 'electrical')
```

expected result should be:

```
array('1254', '1255')
```

Need a way that will return the match index, just like _.findIndex in lodash Javascript library.

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: Yeap, almost :)

Comment: So what does that mean?  Still having issues?

Comment: Actually I have created my own method in PHP using recursion. That solve my problem for now.

Answer (score 2):

[array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) can take an array as the needle. `array_search()` returns the first matching key and `array_keys()` will return all matching keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr, array('1' => 'celling', '2' => 'electrical'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop the main array and compare it with search array.

```
 $arr = array(

    '1253' => array('0' => 'av/data'),
    '1254' => array('1' => 'celling', '2' => 'electrical'),
    '1255' => array('1' => 'celling', '2' => 'electrical'),
);

$array_check = array('1' => 'celling', '2' => 'electrical');

foreach($arr as $key=>$val){

    if($val === $array_check){
        $new_array[]=$key;
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: This works fine. Actually i was looking for some build-in function.